# Prove that MergeSort is stable for any input size n ∈ N using induction on n.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, computer-science, sorting

In terms of a list of objects with two separate fields, suppose a stable sort would order the list in increasing order. However, if two elements have the same number, then they'll appear in the same order as in the unsorted list.

I'm confused by what property of the Merge procedure is required for the stability of MergeSort. why? How is this proven? We talked about this in class but i don't understand the concept

- I have trouble with induction as well. Please help.

Comment: The mergesort algorithm is divide and conquer, so you can assume that the two halves are sorted stably and then show that the algorithm stably sorts the whole array. So the merging step is the key thing you would need to analyze.

Comment: We need to prove that mergesort is stable for any input size n ∈ N using induction on n. I've always had trouble with induction and am confused about everything (even the base case). How would I show this with induction?

Comment: Induction on the input size will also work: When you divide an array of size $n \geq 2$, the two halves both have size $ < n$, so by induction, you can assume that both halves are sorted stably. Then you just have to show that when you merge them it results in the whole array being sorted stably.